# FFMPEG (Synology) : Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Tags: video, ffmpeg, nas, encoding, synology-diskstation

I'm trying to convert my avi files into mp4 so that Plex doesn't need to transcode them.
I want to run it from my Synology NAS which has ffmpeg installed.
When I run this command `ffmpeg -i Pilot.avi Pilot.mp4` or a variant I get this :

`ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.9.4 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-169-g87eb166) 20150629 (prerelease)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --incdir='${prefix}/include/ffmpeg' --arch=arm64 --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/usr/local/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi- --enable-cross-compile --enable-optimizations --enable-pic --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-static --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaac --enable-encoders --enable-pthreads --disable-bzlib --disable-protocol=rtp --disable-muxer=image2 --disable-muxer=image2pipe --disable-swscale-alpha --disable-ffserver --disable-ffplay --disable-devices --disable-bzlib --disable-altivec --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --disable-vaapi --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=ac3 --disable-decoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=zmbv --disable-encoder=dca --disable-encoder=ac3 --disable-encoder=ac3_fixed --disable-encoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=dca --disable-decoder=eac3 --disable-decoder=truehd --cc=/usr/local/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnueabi-ccache-gcc --enable-yasm --enable-libx264 --enable-encoder=libx264
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'Pilot.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.4.1 (build 2178/release)
    IAS1            : English
  Duration: 00:36:26.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 893 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Advanced Simple Profile) (XVID / 0x44495658), yuv420p, 512x384 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 779 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 101 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'Pilot.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : VirtualDubMod 1.5.4.1 (build 2178/release)
    IAS1            : English
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, q=2-31, 128 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 0:0, 25 fps
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libfaac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (libfaac))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height`

What is going wrong ? What can I do to correct it?

Thanks

Comment: My first suggestion is to upgrade ffmpeg. But you can try `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 20M -probesize 20M -i Pilot.avi Pilot.mp4`

Comment: How would do I update FFMPEG? I installed it via Synology's package center which claims to be version 4.1-11. The command you suggested doesn't work, but I clearly have a version issue

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the problem.
My NAS is a DS418 which already has ffmpeg 2.7.1 installed. I have to specify that I want the version installed from the package center by running `/var/packages/ffmpeg/target/bin/ffmpeg -i ...`

Comment: Could you run the plain `ffmpeg` command (for this newer version you got) and provide a link to the log/console output? I'd like to see if Synology is still violating the GPL.